# RNFS.exists always returns false even when image is present in gallery in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs

I am trying to check the existence of an image in my mobile storage in my react native app. But even if the file is present it is returning false to me everytime. Am I missing something?Thanks in advance.

This is my imagepath

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4B92ACDC-8DD1-4713-A841-CAFEBD180525/tmp/FB1923E6-A008-4B68-8B8D-6415F247EF59.jpg
```

Code

```
RNFS.exists(imagepath).then((val)=>{
                              if(val){
                                console.log("Exists");
                              }else{
                                console.log("Does not exits");
                              }
                              
                          }).catch((error)=>{
                            console.log(error);
                          })
```

Comment: How do you know the file exists? Base on the path, looks like it's iOS. Some suggestion: [1] Try to check if Document dir is exits (it's default on iOS) `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4B92ACDC-8DD1-4713-A841-CAFEBD180525/Documents`. [2] Try to remove `file://` on the path

Comment: I know the image exists because when i dont use exist function but just render the image with the same path it is visible, so the image is definitely there. I tried removing the `file://` but still it returns false. Surprisingly even checking just the document directory is returning false.

Comment: Then you should review your install steps of RNFS. Try to check other functions like getting the Document dir path. Also maybe a silly question, but have you run `pod instal`l after install RNFS? need to rebuild the iOS app too